# python traceback - performance problems

Tags: python, stack-trace, callstack, traceback

we have a python script that uses a c library to call some low level functions.
Because of code structure reasons we want to store the stack trace/call stack before each c call.

To do this we use `traceback.extract_stack()` to extract the call stack of python.
When an exception occurs later on, we use `traceback.format_list(abc)` on each element to format and print the stack trace.

The problem is that the function `extract_stack` is too slow. I slows down our code from 1.7 seconds to 11 seconds.

**Is there any function to store the stack trace in order to be able to use/print it later?**
The stacktrace getter must be very fast. The format function can be slow, this is no problem.

Example:

```
Stack Trace:
  - LXScript: '_LXS:TOOL:RUNLX'
      File "_LXS:TOOL:RUNLX", line 13, in <module>
      File "lxs", line 1, in <module>
  - UNIFACE ACTIVATE: 'ACTQREC_SVC' 'EXECLXSRP'
  - LXScript: '_DATATRT:ACTQREC:EXECUTE@Main:run'
      File "_LXS:TOOL:RUNLX", line 13, in <module>
      File "lxs", line 1, in <module>
      File "<string>", line 63, in run
      File "<string>", line 97, in __doAll
      File "<string>", line 127, in __do
      File "_DATATRT:ACTQREC:EXECUTE", line 7, in do
  - UNIFACE ACTIVATE: 'ACTQ_CSVC' 'EXECBYREC'
  - LXScript: 'TOOL:ACTQ:SYNLAB_DATA@Main:runOnBeforeExec'
      File "TOOL:ACTQ:SYNLAB_DATA", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named 'localls'
```

Comment: Why not get the stack trace after the exception, so the overhead is only in exceptional circumstances?

Comment: maybe you could use the `limit` parameter to only get a part of the context. In the example above, maybe you don't need all the stack but only the 5 deeper calls. Should speed up operations a bit.

Comment: @PeterWood
Because we don't have the exsiting stacktrace when we enter the c interface from the non python code (uniface).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre
I think this will still be too slow.

Comment: By using a limit of 2, I come to 2,1 seconds. Compared to 1,7 and 11 it makes a big difference!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved the problem!!!

We can use `stt_obj = sys._getframe().f_back` to get the "`<frame>`?" And then we can use `estt_obj = traceback.extract_stack(f=stt_obj)` and `traceback.format_list(estt_obj)` to get the stack trace as string list.

Comment: Could you show where `elem` and `self` exist to read `STT_OBJ`?

Comment: Fantastic thank you - this really works, `f` is a frame! I wish that was clearer in the docs